# Как указать в форме обратной связи ссылки страницы, на которых был сделан заказ?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Есть лендинг, на которм 5 форм обратной связи, они практически одинаковы, но заказчик просит сделать так что бы на почту приходила информация с какой именно формы пришел заказ, как это реализовать?

Пример кода одной из форм:

```html
<form class="form-1" id="form-1">
  <div class="border__frame">
    <div class="heading">Отправьте <span>заявку на марс!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="description">И наш марсианский менеджер перезвонит вам в ближйшее время.</div>
    <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="30" placeholder="Ваше имя" required>
    <input class="index__phone" name="code" type="tel" maxlength="3" placeholder="123" required>
    <input class="number__phone" name="tel" type="tel" maxlength="10" placeholder="325-54-94" required>
    <button class="btn-submit-mars" type="submit">Отправить заявку на марс</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

```js
 $("#form-1").validate({
   rules: {
     name: {
       required: true,
       minlength: 2
     },

     code: {
       required: true,
       digits: true,
       minlength: 3,
       maxlength: 3
     },

     tel: {
       required: true,
       digits: true,
       minlength: 7
     }
   },
   messages: {
     name: {
       required: "Неверно заполнено поле :(",
       minlength: "Минимальное кол-во символов 2"
     },
     code: {
       required: "Введите код",
       digits: "Обязательно цифры",
       minlength: "3 символа"
     },
     tel: {
       required: "Введите номер телефона :(",
       digits: "Обязательно цифры",
       minlength: "Минимальное кол-во символов 7"
     }
   }
 });

 $("#form-1").submit(function() {

   if ($("#form-1").valid()) {

     var th = $(this);
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "mail.php",
       data: th.serialize()
     }).done(function() {

       $(".success").addClass("visible");
       setTimeout(function() {
         // Done Functions
         th.trigger("reset");
         $(".success").removeClass("visible");
       }, 1000);

       $('#form-1')[0].reset(
         setTimeout(function() {}, 1000)
       );

       $("#form-1").hide();

       $('.mfp-bg.mfp-ready').css({
         'display': 'none'
       });


       $('#popUpMessage').removeClass('hiddenDiv');
       setTimeout(function() {
         $('#popUpMessage').addClass('hiddenDiv');
       }, 4000);
     });
   }
   return false;
 });
```

и сам обработчик mail.php

```html
<?php

$recepient = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
$sitename = "Марсоход";

$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
$code = trim($_POST["code"]);
$tel = trim($_POST["tel"]);
$message = trim($_POST["message"]);
$message = "Имя: $name \nТелефон: $code $tel \nВопрос: $message";

$pagetitle = "Новое сообщение с сайта \"$sitename\"";
mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient");
```

Меня интересует: это что нужно для каждой формы отдельный обработчик, если нет то как это уместить в один, и что бы эти заголовки-метки о страницах там отобразить? Помогите советом. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть много вариантов, например

1. добавить в форму `hidden` поле с названием формы
2. Добавлять в js при отправке в data либо текущий url либо опять же название формы *(этот вариант мне больше нравится)*

**UPD**

```
     var th = $(this).serialize();
     th.push({name: 'form_name', value: 'name'});
     th.push({name: 'form_url', value: window.location.pathname});
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "mail.php",
      data: th
    }).done(function() {
```

Взято отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627936/jquery-post-with-serialize-and-extra-data

Comment: а можно более детально о втором варианте? не очень силен в js, и сходу понять трудно как это реализовать

Comment: теперь письма не отправляются